# Google Sheets: Transposing entry table with query to Date as columns and Name as rows

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to use the query function to reorganize a data entry table so that it can be displayed with names of employees as rows and dates as columns.

In the image below, I am trying to turn the first table into the second table.

[image]

I tried using the query and transpose function, but I don't understand how to handle missing entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=query(A2:C,"Select Col2, sum(Col3) Where Col2<>'' group by Col2 pivot Col1")
```

[image]